# $2^n$ contains 9 in base 10 if $n \geq 109$?

Tags: number-theory

While working on https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/11wds6n/repeated_doubling_conjecture/ I observed that the decimal expansion of $2^n$ appears to contain a $9$ when $n \geq 109$.

Can/has this been proven?

Comment: This sounds like one of those simple number theory statements that is a nightmare to prove.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is such an arbitrary, haphazard question that really shouldn't command much attention.  Suppose someone said $3^{11}$ base 6 had 4s for $n >91$... would we want to work on that too?  Or care?

Comment: I would probably call it a nightmare to disprove

Answer (score 3):

Most such conjectures are very hard to prove. At heart, the digits of a number in base $10$ (or any other base) are not tightly associated with algebraic properties of the number.

There are easy ways to compute heuristics - reasons to guess when such things are likely true.

If we treat the digits as random, the probability seems high. There are at least $1+3\lfloor n/10\rfloor$ digits in $2^n$ so the probability that there isn't a $9$ is $p_n\leq\left(\frac9{10}\right)^{3\lfloor n/10\rfloor},$

So the "expected number" of counter-examples is:

$$\sum_{n=129}^{\infty} p_n \leq 3\sum_{m=43}^{\infty}\left(\frac9{10}\right)^m=30\cdot\left(\frac9{10}\right)^{43}\approx 0.323$$

But presumably, you've checked a number of values bigger than $129,$ so the probabilistic heuristic will give you a smaller expected value, since you are starting at a larger $n.$

There is nothing about this that is specific to $9.$ We can get tighter probabilities for even non-zero digits, because the last digits cycle through $2,4,8,6,$ thus eliminating the number of possible counter-examples.

It seems likely to me that it is true that:

> For each base $b$ and $a>1$ with $b^n\neq a^m$ for any integers $m,n>0,$  and any sequence $D$ of base $b$ digits, there is an $N_{D}$ such that, for all $n>N_d,$ $a^n$ in base $b$ contains the sequence.

(The $b^n\neq a^m$ rules out cases like $b=8, a=4,$ where the digits if $a^n$ in base $b$ form an easy pattern.)

But digits are not really random numbers. And we don't really have the tools to prove such things.

Essentially, our intuition is that for large $n,$ the digits of $2^n$ act "like" random numbers.